# Solomon Islands - Getting from Munda to Gizo by boat

Tags: solomon-islands, munda, gizo

I know there are flights from Munda to Gizo. But the distance is very short (10 minutes flight time).

Is it possible to go by boat from Munda to Gizo? How would I take such a boat?

Comment: Are you aware of the travel-time differences here?  10 minutes by plane could be the same as 5-10 HOURS or more by a Solomons banana boat.  A ferry might be faster (probably not by much), but I can't find any between Munda and Gizo.